# How to obtain a property from Application Setting in IIS with powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

Using PowerShell, I would like to get the values of Application Settings of all websites in IIS. See picture.
[Application Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkMrd.png)

The command will save in a variable the sites that have "MonitoringEnabled True".

```
$sitesList = Get-IISSite
$sitesIIS = $sitesList | Where-Object {$_.MonitoringEnabled -eq "True"}
$siteInfoHealth=@()
foreach($site in $sitesIIS)
   {$siteInfo = Invoke-WebRequest $site
       if($siteInfo.ContainsValue("OK"))
       {
       $siteInforHealth += @{Healthy = 'True' }
       }
        else{$siteInfoHealth += @{Healthy = 'False'}
       }
    }
 $siteInfoHealth | ConvertTo-json | out-file "C:/health.json"
```

Comment: And what is the question? :-) Does `$sitesList | Where-Object {$_.MoitoringEnabled -eq "True"}` return a different result than what you expected? Or do you need it to return something else and are unsure how?

Comment: I would need to obtain the value “MonitoringEnabled True”. There are some sites that I do not want to monitor and they have “MonitoringEnabled False”. 

I am unsure how to search all sites in IIS and save only the sites that have MonitoringEnabled True in a variable.

Comment: When you set eq "True", do you get more than just the value "MonitoringEnabled True"? Does it contain true and false?

Comment: In our IIS, we have a list sites and apps that we require to check if site is healthy with a script which will run in a task scheduler.  All of them has MonitoringEnabled with a True or False value which was added manually. True is set for those sites we want to check.